# Default kernel in jupyter notebook (Python3) not working

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 having Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10.
When I launch Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda3 Navigator using environment: base(root), it shows kernel error and Python 3 (which is default kernel) as dead kernel.

The kernel error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
>       result = await result
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
>       type=mtype))
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
>       kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
>       self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
>       yielded = next(result)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
>       super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
>       km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
>       self.write_connection_file()
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
>       kernel_name=self.kernel_name
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
>       with secure_write(fname) as f:
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 100, in secure_write
>       win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
>     File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 53, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
>       import win32api
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

I am new to Python and anaconda, please help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the slew of error you are getting, i advise you to reinstall anaconda on windows 10. Kernel errors aren't easily solved. So, reinstalling is the easiest way to solve this... given link should help:===>

[Installing anaconda on W10](https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/01-Orientation/01.03-Installing-Anaconda-on-Windows/)

Answer (score 0):

1)In jupyter notebook if you find "kernel dead" then click file and select close and halt option.When notebook gets closed you can go to kernel and click restart.

2) If the above instruction didn't work then uninstall and install the following packages

```
    jupyter_client
    jupyter_core
    ipykernel
    ipython
    ipython_genutils 
    traitlets
```