# Jupyter Lab and Notebook Problem: Kernel Error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, python-3.6, jupyter-lab

It appears that somehow one of my kernels is deleted. And perhaps that's why I am getting this error. How could I possibly fix it? Can I reinstall something (the kernel in the **base environment** perhaps)?

If no better option is available, I would try reinstalling anaconda altogether as a last resort according to: [Default kernel in jupyter notebook (Python3) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200576/default-kernel-in-jupyter-notebook-python3-not-working).

[image]

I have tried using the following:

1. [Installation of Jupyter Lab: `requirements already satisfied`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html)
2. [Kernels don't show up when runnning "jupyter lab"](https://github.com/QuantStack/xeus-cling/issues/177)
3. [UI says "No kernel" while I definitively have one](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1018)
4. [Getting Kernel Error while running Jupyter Notebook in Python3](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3556)
5. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html
6. https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/recovering-from-a-jupyter-disaster-27401677aeeb

### Current List of Kernels

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Output:

```
Available kernels:
  python3    C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3
  vpython    C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\vpython
```

But I must have another kernel (which I suppose somehow got deleted) associated with my base environment.

```
C:\Users\raysu\Documents>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64
astra_env                C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\envs\astra_env
bokeh_env                C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\envs\bokeh_env
sound_env                C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\envs\sound_env
tf_env                   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\envs\tf_env
                         C:\Users\raysu\Anaconda3
                         C:\Users\raysu\Anaconda3\envs\pyforge
opencv_env               C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\opencv_env
test_env                 C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\test_env
```

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 476, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 141, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 404, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 359, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Anaconda makes things difficult to troubleshoot.  I bailed on Anaconda years ago and have been happily coding ever since.

Comment: @Gray I was able to solve it finally. I hope the solution helps others who come across similar `kernel error` problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Solved the problem by editing the relevant `kernelspec`: `kernel.json` file after fresh installation of Anaconda.**

## Solution in Detail

As reported earlier, I found that I had **two** `kernelspecs`. (command: `jupyter kernelspec list`)

1. python3:    `C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3`
2. vpython:    `C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\vpython`

The `kernelspec` is a `.json` file that maintains kernel-specifications for jupyter-notebook/lab to launch a certain kernel. Fortunately, the kernel **`vpython`** was functioning and that helped me narrow down the source of the problem located inside **`kernelpsec: python3`**. I had to correct the path to the python executable (`python.exe`) and that solved the issue.

I would like to mention that in this case the following two resources came handy. I got more clarity in where the problem could be, after I saw the *typical-structure* of the `kernelspec` document.

**Note:** However, since I cannot test this theory, I would ask anyone else in a similar problem, to first make a copy of the old `kernel.json` file and then update the path to `python.exe` file. If that resolves the ***kernel error***, then reinstalling Anaconda altogether may not be necessary.

> ## Long story short:

If your jupyter notebook/lab environment shows you **kernel error**, most likely the source of the problem is inside the kernelspec file: **`kernel.json`** and the path to **`python.exe`** is incorrect. This could be a more likely scenario, if the same `kernel error` persists even after fresh re-installation of anaconda/jupyter-notebook/lab.

For instance, in my case, the `python3-kernelspec` was located at:

```
"C:\Users\raysu\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3"
```

And the `python.exe` was located at:

```
"C:\Users\raysu\Anaconda3\python.exe"
```

However, the path to the *python-executable* was wrong: it was still showing the path from the old installation. And post-anaconda-reinstallation, this path had changed. So, I had to update the kernelspec for python3 by editing `kernel.json` file.

```
# kernel.json file
{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Users\\raysu\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

If this does not solve your problem, please consult the following two documents. I wasted 4 days because of this. Hopefully, this answer would help out someone in future.

### What came handy?

1. https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html
2. https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html

Comment: Thanks!
I had initially installed python 3.10 and then anaconda, which comes with a 3.8 version instead. uninstalling both and reinstalling just anaconda, caused this issue. It is unfortunate that it is not easy to make a trully clean unistall of either.

Comment: @alex Don't install python outside anaconda. Once you install anaconda, you can install python 3.10 by creating a new environment like so: `conda create -n py310 python=3.10 -c conda-forge`. See this answer on how to use conda properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66560897/8474894.

Comment: My Jupyterlab was working alright for a very long time, and one fine morning, I got this error. The jupyter kernelspec list showed me one item in list, and everything else seemd to be alright. Things started working normally after upgrading the jupyter-client from 5.3.3 to 7.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the problem 
[here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4907#issuecomment-541363329)

I installed  jupyter_client 5.3.4 and jupyter_core 4.6.0 with this command

```
pip install jupyter_client --upgrade
```

Comment: So how?  What was the resolution for the problem?

Comment: @Odunsi The problem you mentioned about is referring to [PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied #4907](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4907#issuecomment-541363329). It does not look like the same kerner error mentioned in the question here. Does it?

Comment: It doesn't. But I was thinking maybe they are both related.

Answer (score 0):

The most upvoted answer is correct even when you are getting [Winerror 2] just like me. Go to the kernel json and change the path to the Anaconda3 python.exe and problem will be most likely solved.