# How do I fix this decoder.py file error when launching Jupyter Lab and/or Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I had an old version of Anaconda and have reinstalled it afresh. It is the latest 64-bit version available as of 3/5/2020. I have not added anaconda to the PATH environment variable. I am trying to open Jupyter Notebook and/or Jupyter Lab, but I get multiple errors. The direct effect of the error on the Jupyter Lab/Notebook is that no kernel is recognized. I can't run any Python programs.

Contents of "encoder.py" (below):

```
"""Implementation of JSONEncoder
"""
import re

try:
    from _json import encode_basestring_ascii as c_encode_basestring_ascii
except ImportError:
    c_encode_basestring_ascii = None
try:
    from _json import encode_basestring as c_encode_basestring
except ImportError:
    c_encode_basestring = None
try:
    from _json import make_encoder as c_make_encoder
except ImportError:
    c_make_encoder = None

ESCAPE = re.compile(r'[\x00-\x1f\\"\b\f\n\r\t]')
ESCAPE_ASCII = re.compile(r'([\\"]|[^\ -~])')
HAS_UTF8 = re.compile(b'[\x80-\xff]')
ESCAPE_DCT = {
    '\\': '\\\\',
    '"': '\\"',
    '\b': '\\b',
    '\f': '\\f',
    '\n': '\\n',
    '\r': '\\r',
    '\t': '\\t',
}
for i in range(0x20):
    ESCAPE_DCT.setdefault(chr(i), '\\u{0:04x}'.format(i))
    #ESCAPE_DCT.setdefault(chr(i), '\\u%04x' % (i,))

INFINITY = float('inf')

def py_encode_basestring(s):
    """Return a JSON representation of a Python string

    """
    def replace(match):
        return ESCAPE_DCT[match.group(0)]
    return '"' + ESCAPE.sub(replace, s) + '"'


encode_basestring = (c_encode_basestring or py_encode_basestring)


def py_encode_basestring_ascii(s):
    """Return an ASCII-only JSON representation of a Python string

    """
    def replace(match):
        s = match.group(0)
        try:
            return ESCAPE_DCT[s]
        except KeyError:
            n = ord(s)
            if n < 0x10000:
                return '\\u{0:04x}'.format(n)
                #return '\\u%04x' % (n,)
            else:
                # surrogate pair
                n -= 0x10000
                s1 = 0xd800 | ((n >> 10) & 0x3ff)
                s2 = 0xdc00 | (n & 0x3ff)
                return '\\u{0:04x}\\u{1:04x}'.format(s1, s2)
    return '"' + ESCAPE_ASCII.sub(replace, s) + '"'


encode_basestring_ascii = (
    c_encode_basestring_ascii or py_encode_basestring_ascii)

class JSONEncoder(object):
    """Extensible JSON <http://json.org> encoder for Python data structures.

    Supports the following objects and types by default:

    +-------------------+---------------+
    | Python            | JSON          |
    +===================+===============+
    | dict              | object        |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | list, tuple       | array         |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | str               | string        |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | int, float        | number        |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | True              | true          |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | False             | false         |
    +-------------------+---------------+
    | None              | null          |
    +-------------------+---------------+

    To extend this to recognize other objects, subclass and implement a
    ``.default()`` method with another method that returns a serializable
    object for ``o`` if possible, otherwise it should call the superclass
    implementation (to raise ``TypeError``).

    """
    item_separator = ', '
    key_separator = ': '
    def __init__(self, *, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True,
            check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, sort_keys=False,
            indent=None, separators=None, default=None):
        """Constructor for JSONEncoder, with sensible defaults.

        If skipkeys is false, then it is a TypeError to attempt
        encoding of keys that are not str, int, float or None.  If
        skipkeys is True, such items are simply skipped.

        If ensure_ascii is true, the output is guaranteed to be str
        objects with all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped.  If
        ensure_ascii is false, the output can contain non-ASCII characters.

        If check_circular is true, then lists, dicts, and custom encoded
        objects will be checked for circular references during encoding to
        prevent an infinite recursion (which would cause an OverflowError).
        Otherwise, no such check takes place.

        If allow_nan is true, then NaN, Infinity, and -Infinity will be
        encoded as such.  This behavior is not JSON specification compliant,
        but is consistent with most JavaScript based encoders and decoders.
        Otherwise, it will be a ValueError to encode such floats.

        If sort_keys is true, then the output of dictionaries will be
        sorted by key; this is useful for regression tests to ensure
        that JSON serializations can be compared on a day-to-day basis.

        If indent is a non-negative integer, then JSON array
        elements and object members will be pretty-printed with that
        indent level.  An indent level of 0 will only insert newlines.
        None is the most compact representation.

        If specified, separators should be an (item_separator, key_separator)
        tuple.  The default is (', ', ': ') if *indent* is ``None`` and
        (',', ': ') otherwise.  To get the most compact JSON representation,
        you should specify (',', ':') to eliminate whitespace.

        If specified, default is a function that gets called for objects
        that can't otherwise be serialized.  It should return a JSON encodable
        version of the object or raise a ``TypeError``.

        """

        self.skipkeys = skipkeys
        self.ensure_ascii = ensure_ascii
        self.check_circular = check_circular
        self.allow_nan = allow_nan
        self.sort_keys = sort_keys
        self.indent = indent
        if separators is not None:
            self.item_separator, self.key_separator = separators
        elif indent is not None:
            self.item_separator = ','
        if default is not None:
            self.default = default

    def default(self, o):
        """Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
        a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
        (to raise a ``TypeError``).

        For example, to support arbitrary iterators, you could
        implement default like this::

            def default(self, o):
                try:
                    iterable = iter(o)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
                else:
                    return list(iterable)
                # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
                return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

        """
        raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
                        f'is not JSON serializable')

    def encode(self, o):
        """Return a JSON string representation of a Python data structure.

        >>> from json.encoder import JSONEncoder
        >>> JSONEncoder().encode({"foo": ["bar", "baz"]})
        '{"foo": ["bar", "baz"]}'

        """
        # This is for extremely simple cases and benchmarks.
        if isinstance(o, str):
            if self.ensure_ascii:
                return encode_basestring_ascii(o)
            else:
                return encode_basestring(o)
        # This doesn't pass the iterator directly to ''.join() because the
        # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
        # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
        if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
            chunks = list(chunks)
        return ''.join(chunks)

    def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):
        """Encode the given object and yield each string
        representation as available.

        For example::

            for chunk in JSONEncoder().iterencode(bigobject):
                mysocket.write(chunk)

        """
        if self.check_circular:
            markers = {}
        else:
            markers = None
        if self.ensure_ascii:
            _encoder = encode_basestring_ascii
        else:
            _encoder = encode_basestring

        def floatstr(o, allow_nan=self.allow_nan,
                _repr=float.__repr__, _inf=INFINITY, _neginf=-INFINITY):
            # Check for specials.  Note that this type of test is processor
            # and/or platform-specific, so do tests which don't depend on the
            # internals.

            if o != o:
                text = 'NaN'
            elif o == _inf:
                text = 'Infinity'
            elif o == _neginf:
                text = '-Infinity'
            else:
                return _repr(o)

            if not allow_nan:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Out of range float values are not JSON compliant: " +
                    repr(o))

            return text


        if (_one_shot and c_make_encoder is not None
                and self.indent is None):
            _iterencode = c_make_encoder(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, self.allow_nan)
        else:
            _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
        return _iterencode(o, 0)

def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,
        _key_separator, _item_separator, _sort_keys, _skipkeys, _one_shot,
        ## HACK: hand-optimized bytecode; turn globals into locals
        ValueError=ValueError,
        dict=dict,
        float=float,
        id=id,
        int=int,
        isinstance=isinstance,
        list=list,
        str=str,
        tuple=tuple,
        _intstr=int.__str__,
    ):

    if _indent is not None and not isinstance(_indent, str):
        _indent = ' ' * _indent

    def _iterencode_list(lst, _current_indent_level):
        if not lst:
            yield '[]'
            return
        if markers is not None:
            markerid = id(lst)
            if markerid in markers:
                raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
            markers[markerid] = lst
        buf = '['
        if _indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level += 1
            newline_indent = '\n' + _indent * _current_indent_level
            separator = _item_separator + newline_indent
            buf += newline_indent
        else:
            newline_indent = None
            separator = _item_separator
        first = True
        for value in lst:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                buf = separator
            if isinstance(value, str):
                yield buf + _encoder(value)
            elif value is None:
                yield buf + 'null'
            elif value is True:
                yield buf + 'true'
            elif value is False:
                yield buf + 'false'
            elif isinstance(value, int):
                # Subclasses of int/float may override __str__, but we still
                # want to encode them as integers/floats in JSON. One example
                # within the standard library is IntEnum.
                yield buf + _intstr(value)
            elif isinstance(value, float):
                # see comment above for int
                yield buf + _floatstr(value)
            else:
                yield buf
                if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    chunks = _iterencode_list(value, _current_indent_level)
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    chunks = _iterencode_dict(value, _current_indent_level)
                else:
                    chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
                yield from chunks
        if newline_indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level -= 1
            yield '\n' + _indent * _current_indent_level
        yield ']'
        if markers is not None:
            del markers[markerid]

    def _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level):
        if not dct:
            yield '{}'
            return
        if markers is not None:
            markerid = id(dct)
            if markerid in markers:
                raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
            markers[markerid] = dct
        yield '{'
        if _indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level += 1
            newline_indent = '\n' + _indent * _current_indent_level
            item_separator = _item_separator + newline_indent
            yield newline_indent
        else:
            newline_indent = None
            item_separator = _item_separator
        first = True
        if _sort_keys:
            items = sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])
        else:
            items = dct.items()
        for key, value in items:
            if isinstance(key, str):
                pass
            # JavaScript is weakly typed for these, so it makes sense to
            # also allow them.  Many encoders seem to do something like this.
            elif isinstance(key, float):
                # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
                key = _floatstr(key)
            elif key is True:
                key = 'true'
            elif key is False:
                key = 'false'
            elif key is None:
                key = 'null'
            elif isinstance(key, int):
                # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
                key = _intstr(key)
            elif _skipkeys:
                continue
            else:
                raise TypeError(f'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, '
                                f'not {key.__class__.__name__}')
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                yield item_separator
            yield _encoder(key)
            yield _key_separator
            if isinstance(value, str):
                yield _encoder(value)
            elif value is None:
                yield 'null'
            elif value is True:
                yield 'true'
            elif value is False:
                yield 'false'
            elif isinstance(value, int):
                # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
                yield _intstr(value)
            elif isinstance(value, float):
                # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
                yield _floatstr(value)
            else:
                if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    chunks = _iterencode_list(value, _current_indent_level)
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    chunks = _iterencode_dict(value, _current_indent_level)
                else:
                    chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
                yield from chunks
        if newline_indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level -= 1
            yield '\n' + _indent * _current_indent_level
        yield '}'
        if markers is not None:
            del markers[markerid]

    def _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            yield _encoder(o)
        elif o is None:
            yield 'null'
        elif o is True:
            yield 'true'
        elif o is False:
            yield 'false'
        elif isinstance(o, int):
            # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
            yield _intstr(o)
        elif isinstance(o, float):
            # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
            yield _floatstr(o)
        elif isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
            yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
        else:
            if markers is not None:
                markerid = id(o)
                if markerid in markers:
                    raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
                markers[markerid] = o
            o = _default(o)
            yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
            if markers is not None:
                del markers[markerid]
    return _iterencode
```

Contents of "decoder.py" (below):

```
"""Implementation of JSONDecoder
"""
import re

from json import scanner
try:
    from _json import scanstring as c_scanstring
except ImportError:
    c_scanstring = None

__all__ = ['JSONDecoder', 'JSONDecodeError']

FLAGS = re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL

NaN = float('nan')
PosInf = float('inf')
NegInf = float('-inf')


class JSONDecodeError(ValueError):
    """Subclass of ValueError with the following additional properties:

    msg: The unformatted error message
    doc: The JSON document being parsed
    pos: The start index of doc where parsing failed
    lineno: The line corresponding to pos
    colno: The column corresponding to pos

    """
    # Note that this exception is used from _json
    def __init__(self, msg, doc, pos):
        lineno = doc.count('\n', 0, pos) + 1
        colno = pos - doc.rfind('\n', 0, pos)
        errmsg = '%s: line %d column %d (char %d)' % (msg, lineno, colno, pos)
        ValueError.__init__(self, errmsg)
        self.msg = msg
        self.doc = doc
        self.pos = pos
        self.lineno = lineno
        self.colno = colno

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (self.msg, self.doc, self.pos)


_CONSTANTS = {
    '-Infinity': NegInf,
    'Infinity': PosInf,
    'NaN': NaN,
}


STRINGCHUNK = re.compile(r'(.*?)(["\\\x00-\x1f])', FLAGS)
BACKSLASH = {
    '"': '"', '\\': '\\', '/': '/',
    'b': '\b', 'f': '\f', 'n': '\n', 'r': '\r', 't': '\t',
}

def _decode_uXXXX(s, pos):
    esc = s[pos + 1:pos + 5]
    if len(esc) == 4 and esc[1] not in 'xX':
        try:
            return int(esc, 16)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    msg = "Invalid \\uXXXX escape"
    raise JSONDecodeError(msg, s, pos)

def py_scanstring(s, end, strict=True,
        _b=BACKSLASH, _m=STRINGCHUNK.match):
    """Scan the string s for a JSON string. End is the index of the
    character in s after the quote that started the JSON string.
    Unescapes all valid JSON string escape sequences and raises ValueError
    on attempt to decode an invalid string. If strict is False then literal
    control characters are allowed in the string.

    Returns a tuple of the decoded string and the index of the character in s
    after the end quote."""
    chunks = []
    _append = chunks.append
    begin = end - 1
    while 1:
        chunk = _m(s, end)
        if chunk is None:
            raise JSONDecodeError("Unterminated string starting at", s, begin)
        end = chunk.end()
        content, terminator = chunk.groups()
        # Content is contains zero or more unescaped string characters
        if content:
            _append(content)
        # Terminator is the end of string, a literal control character,
        # or a backslash denoting that an escape sequence follows
        if terminator == '"':
            break
        elif terminator != '\\':
            if strict:
                #msg = "Invalid control character %r at" % (terminator,)
                msg = "Invalid control character {0!r} at".format(terminator)
                raise JSONDecodeError(msg, s, end)
            else:
                _append(terminator)
                continue
        try:
            esc = s[end]
        except IndexError:
            raise JSONDecodeError("Unterminated string starting at",
                                  s, begin) from None
        # If not a unicode escape sequence, must be in the lookup table
        if esc != 'u':
            try:
                char = _b[esc]
            except KeyError:
                msg = "Invalid \\escape: {0!r}".format(esc)
                raise JSONDecodeError(msg, s, end)
            end += 1
        else:
            uni = _decode_uXXXX(s, end)
            end += 5
            if 0xd800 <= uni <= 0xdbff and s[end:end + 2] == '\\u':
                uni2 = _decode_uXXXX(s, end + 1)
                if 0xdc00 <= uni2 <= 0xdfff:
                    uni = 0x10000 + (((uni - 0xd800) << 10) | (uni2 - 0xdc00))
                    end += 6
            char = chr(uni)
        _append(char)
    return ''.join(chunks), end


# Use speedup if available
scanstring = c_scanstring or py_scanstring

WHITESPACE = re.compile(r'[ \t\n\r]*', FLAGS)
WHITESPACE_STR = ' \t\n\r'


def JSONObject(s_and_end, strict, scan_once, object_hook, object_pairs_hook,
               memo=None, _w=WHITESPACE.match, _ws=WHITESPACE_STR):
    s, end = s_and_end
    pairs = []
    pairs_append = pairs.append
    # Backwards compatibility
    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
    memo_get = memo.setdefault
    # Use a slice to prevent IndexError from being raised, the following
    # check will raise a more specific ValueError if the string is empty
    nextchar = s[end:end + 1]
    # Normally we expect nextchar == '"'
    if nextchar != '"':
        if nextchar in _ws:
            end = _w(s, end).end()
            nextchar = s[end:end + 1]
        # Trivial empty object
        if nextchar == '}':
            if object_pairs_hook is not None:
                result = object_pairs_hook(pairs)
                return result, end + 1
            pairs = {}
            if object_hook is not None:
                pairs = object_hook(pairs)
            return pairs, end + 1
        elif nextchar != '"':
            raise JSONDecodeError(
                "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes", s, end)
    end += 1
    while True:
        key, end = scanstring(s, end, strict)
        key = memo_get(key, key)
        # To skip some function call overhead we optimize the fast paths where
        # the JSON key separator is ": " or just ":".
        if s[end:end + 1] != ':':
            end = _w(s, end).end()
            if s[end:end + 1] != ':':
                raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting ':' delimiter", s, end)
        end += 1

        try:
            if s[end] in _ws:
                end += 1
                if s[end] in _ws:
                    end = _w(s, end + 1).end()
        except IndexError:
            pass

        try:
            value, end = scan_once(s, end)
        except StopIteration as err:
            raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        pairs_append((key, value))
        try:
            nextchar = s[end]
            if nextchar in _ws:
                end = _w(s, end + 1).end()
                nextchar = s[end]
        except IndexError:
            nextchar = ''
        end += 1

        if nextchar == '}':
            break
        elif nextchar != ',':
            raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting ',' delimiter", s, end - 1)
        end = _w(s, end).end()
        nextchar = s[end:end + 1]
        end += 1
        if nextchar != '"':
            raise JSONDecodeError(
                "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes", s, end - 1)
    if object_pairs_hook is not None:
        result = object_pairs_hook(pairs)
        return result, end
    pairs = dict(pairs)
    if object_hook is not None:
        pairs = object_hook(pairs)
    return pairs, end

def JSONArray(s_and_end, scan_once, _w=WHITESPACE.match, _ws=WHITESPACE_STR):
    s, end = s_and_end
    values = []
    nextchar = s[end:end + 1]
    if nextchar in _ws:
        end = _w(s, end + 1).end()
        nextchar = s[end:end + 1]
    # Look-ahead for trivial empty array
    if nextchar == ']':
        return values, end + 1
    _append = values.append
    while True:
        try:
            value, end = scan_once(s, end)
        except StopIteration as err:
            raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        _append(value)
        nextchar = s[end:end + 1]
        if nextchar in _ws:
            end = _w(s, end + 1).end()
            nextchar = s[end:end + 1]
        end += 1
        if nextchar == ']':
            break
        elif nextchar != ',':
            raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting ',' delimiter", s, end - 1)
        try:
            if s[end] in _ws:
                end += 1
                if s[end] in _ws:
                    end = _w(s, end + 1).end()
        except IndexError:
            pass

    return values, end


class JSONDecoder(object):
    """Simple JSON <http://json.org> decoder

    Performs the following translations in decoding by default:

    +---------------+-------------------+
    | JSON          | Python            |
    +===============+===================+
    | object        | dict              |
    +---------------+-------------------+
    | array         | list              |
    +---------------+-------------------+
    | string        | str               |
    +---------------+-------------------+
    | number (int)  | int               |
    +---------------+-------------------+
    | number (real) | float             |
    +---------------+-------------------+
    | true          | True              |
    +---------------+-------------------+
    | false         | False             |
    +---------------+-------------------+
    | null          | None              |
    +---------------+-------------------+

    It also understands ``NaN``, ``Infinity``, and ``-Infinity`` as
    their corresponding ``float`` values, which is outside the JSON spec.

    """

    def __init__(self, *, object_hook=None, parse_float=None,
            parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, strict=True,
            object_pairs_hook=None):
        self.object_hook = object_hook
        self.parse_float = parse_float or float
        self.parse_int = parse_int or int
        self.parse_constant = parse_constant or _CONSTANTS.__getitem__
        self.strict = strict
        self.object_pairs_hook = object_pairs_hook
        self.parse_object = JSONObject
        self.parse_array = JSONArray
        self.parse_string = scanstring
        self.memo = {}
        self.scan_once = scanner.make_scanner(self)


    def decode(self, s, _w=WHITESPACE.match):

        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
        end = _w(s, end).end()
        if end != len(s):
            raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
        return obj

    def raw_decode(self, s, idx=0):
        try:
            obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
        except StopIteration as err:
            raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        return obj, end
```

The error is:

```
      File "C:\Users\Omkos\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 47, in from_resource_dir
        kernel_dict = json.load(f)
      File "C:\Users\Omkos\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
        parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\Omkos\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Users\Omkos\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Users\Omkos\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
        obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 3 column 6 (char 18)
[W 15:52:51.010 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
[W 15:52:52.541 LabApp] Error loading kernelspec 'python3'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Omkos\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 258, in get_all_specs
        spec = self._get_kernel_spec_by_name(kname, resource_dir)
      File "C:\Users\Omkos\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\kernelspec.py", line 201, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
```

I simply go to Anaconda Prompt `(base) C:\Users\Omkos>` and type in `jupyter lab`. And then, the error pops up after launching the Jupyter Notebook/Lab, also, there is no available kernel. I am at a complete loss on how to fix this. Thanks for all help!

Comment: Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58512041/4739755) - it goes over fixing a simlar error after a fresh install of Anaconda

Comment: Thanks a lot! The instructions on the thread got it all fixed up!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Lab and Notebook Problem: Kernel Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459493/jupyter-lab-and-notebook-problem-kernel-error)

Comment: Yes, the above thread also helps fix the same issue, thanks!